# How to add some lines variable number of times in a function?

Tags: go, code-generation, go-jennifer

I'm using Jennifer which is a code generator for Go. 
I want to write code to generate the `main` function such that some lines could be `count` number of times, where `count` is a variable I read from a file.

I tried creating the required string using `for` loop and passing it in the arguments, but the `Block()` only accepts type `Code`.

```
functoret := jen.Func().Id("main").Params().Block(
jen.Id("a").Op(":=").Id("b")
jen.Id("a").Op(":=").Id("c")
jen.Id("a").Op(":=").Id("d") //count number of times
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block accepts a slice of code fragments, so build the slice first and then call Block:

```
code := []jen.Code{
    jen.Id("a").Op(":=").Id("b"),
    jen.Id("a").Op(":=").Id("c"),
}
for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
    code = append(code, jen.Id("a").Op(":=").Id("d"))
}

functoret := jen.Func().Id("main").Params().Block(code...)
```

Alternatively, use the [BlockFunc](https://godoc.org/github.com/dave/jennifer/jen#Statement.BlockFunc) and [Group.Add methods](https://godoc.org/github.com/dave/jennifer/jen#Group.Add):

```
functoret := jen.Func().Id("main").Params().BlockFunc(func(g *jen.Group) {
    g.Add(jen.Id("a").Op(":=").Id("b"))
    g.Add(jen.Id("a").Op(":=").Id("c"))

    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        g.Add(jen.Id("a").Op(":=").Id("d"))
    }
})
```

Comment: Does the second approach guarantee the inclusion of `a:=d` inside the curly braces defined by `Block()`?

Comment: @ParthVerma, it doesn't, actually; good call. See updated answer.